# How do I get the value of the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my input field:

```
$("<td class='testclass'><input id='field-search' value='' type='text'></td>")
```

How do I get the value of the input field?

I tried it this way:

```
var mytest =$('#field-search').val();
alert(mytest);
```

The result is that I get an alert being undefined though the input field has got a value e.g. 10.

Is there a way to get the value when the value of the input field changes?

A link or an example would be very helpful. Thank you.

Link to the code: http://www.file-upload.net/download-2902420/test.user.js.html

Comment: $("<td class   Why the $ symbol in your html?

Comment: are you sure there is only one element on the page with id of field-search?

Comment: Are you adding it to the page?

Comment: well, this is jQuery ... http://jquery.com/

Comment: @epascarello: Yes. inserting it after a cell with id='field-whatever'. $("<td class='testclass'><input id='field-search' value='' type='text'></td>").insertAfter('#field-whatever');

Comment: @sincerely - try uploading your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ or re-edit the question and add the full code.  What you posted *should* work, unless you haven't actually added the elements you were creating to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've not appended that html to the page. Either do that (`someElement.append($("<td>...</td>"));`), or search in that part specifically

```
var e = $("<td class='testclass'><input id='field-search' value='1' type='text'></td>");
var mytest =e.find('#field-search').val();
alert(mytest);
```

You don't insert element into the page just by calling `$("...")`.

Comment: I updated my answer: http://www.file-upload.net/download-2902420/test.user.js.html

Comment: @sincerely Could you post it on less ad-infested website with English interface and in plain text (without a need to download file)? E.g., jsfiddle.net is popular here.

Comment: I'm sorry, seems like I lost my question already. Sorry for asking.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
var myVal = $('#field-search').val();
```

In vanilla JavaScript

```
var myVal = document.getElementById('field-search').value;
```